# How to Make a list or table containing the product of every three digit integer in mathematica

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to learn the mathematica language. And it was suggested to me to start by doing the Project Euler problems. I am currently working on

Problem # 4: A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

The first step I am taking is learning how to make a table containing the product of every three digit number like, 100x100, 101x100, then using the PalindromeQ function to Print all the palindromes from that table or list.

Any other suggestions would me learn,thanks

Here's what ive tried so far, dont laugh at me:

ATTEMPT #1:
Table[(xx*xx) n, {n, 999}]

Attempt #2
For[i = 100; t = 100, i < 10, i++; t++, t = t*1 =; Print[t]]

Attempt#3
(times = Table[
Inactive[Times][a, b] == a b, {a, 999}, {b, 999}]) // TableForm

Attempt#4 (AFTER TAKING ADVICE FROM YOU ALL)
mydata = Table[a*b, {a, 100, 999}, {b, 100, 999}]
Select[mydata, PalindromeQ]
This only gave me the output of empty brackets, i see that PalindromeQ is the function but it only gives true or false. how do i make a statement where if palindromeQ is true to print Palindrome?
HELP!!

Attempt #5
mydata = Table[a*b, {a, 100, 999}, {b, 100, 999}]
Select[list[mydata], PalindromeQ]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. It is a homework question or a self-learning exercise, so forum participants would appreciate it if you could include copy-paste-able Mathematica code for what you have tried out so far. Thanks.

Comment: ok will post that now

Comment: As for creating a table of products of 3-digit factors, your third attempt is the most promising. Since you're only interested in 3-digit numbers, you can use indices like `{a,100,999}` and `{b,100,999}`.

Comment: I can see that you're trying to produce something that you can inspect visually, but you're going to have a huge table. It would be better to just generate the data, maybe save it in a variable, and then run functions over the data to analyze it. So, dispense with the `Inactive` and `TableForm`. You already had the idea of using `PalindromeQ`, so instead of viaually inspecting, use `Select` and `PalindromeQ` to filter your data.

Comment: You might try this with smaller tables first to avoid any scaling problems you might run into. Make sure your algorithm is working first, then "sneak" up on the final answer.

Comment: I have implemented some elements of the hints you all gave me here.....thanks to @lericr!! I am almost there.....only need help with selecting the palindrome part....can you see my advancements?

Comment: Try: `Select[IntegerDigits[mydata], PalindromeQ]` as the next step. Then explore the `FromDigits` function from the docs.

Comment: I dont see how IntegerDigits would be helpful. According to the Docs, integer digits picks out individual integerdigits or counts them. I want to know which of them are palindrome, not count them  or list the digits individually.

Comment: Is something wrong with my SELECT statement? I tried to test the data table by attempting to find the prime numbers such as Select[mydata, Prime]...still empty brackets....i even tried Select[list[mydata], Prime], even did Select[list[mydata], PrimeQ] to no avail.....

Comment: @Bill, this is what I've tried given your suggestions: INPUT Select[{1, 2, 5, 8}, PrimeQ] OUTPUT {2, 5} INPUT Select[{{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 5}}, PalendromeQ]  OUTPUT { } Then I threw in one of my own for the PalindromeQ INPUT Select[{90009, 12321, 4556554, 98992, 22499}, PalindromeQ]  OUTPUT  {90009, 12321, 4556554}

Comment: Since you have two iterators in your table (a and b), your table is two-dimensional. Easiest thing to do is probably just apply Flatten. I.e. the first argument to your Select would be Flatten[mydata].

Comment: my real data goes from 100-999 but Using a small sample, mydata = Table[a*b, {a, 100, 110}, {b, 100, 110}]  then, INPUT Select[{10100, 10201, 10302, 10403, 10504, 10605, 10706, 10807, 10908,
   11009, 11110}, PalindromeQ]  gives OUTPUT {10201}

Comment: Also, not sure how you're doing this in a notebook, but if you have the Table and the Select in the same cell, you should separate them with semicolon. Of course, you could also just put them in different cells.

Comment: not sure what you mean by notebook but im using mathematica software that came with my raspberry pi,otherwise mathematica is super expensive. im also typing this comment using the browser of the same raspberry pi

Comment: Oh, cool! Well, I don't know what the ux is with RaspberryPi, so just ignore my last comment.

Comment: @lericr THE FLATTEN option worked!!!!!!!! Thank you!!!!!

Comment: As it seems you discovered from the documentation, PalindromeQ is polymorphic in that it can work on Lists, Integers, and Strings. Select works on the first level of a list, so it was the List-oriented version of PalindromeQ that was being applied. Since none of those lists were palindromic, you ended up with nothing matching (an empty list). By flattening the list, now the first elements are all integers, and so the integer-oriented version of PalindromeQ will be used.

Comment: I assume that now you've found your solution. I don't know the power of a RaspberryPi, but on my laptop it works fairly quickly (but not instantaneously). This approach to the problem generates about 900^2 numbers and applies PalindromeQ to them all. You might want to think of a solution that was more efficient. Since you're looking for the largest, you might want to work backward (starting at 999x999 and iterating downward) and stop iterating when you've found a palindrome. Give it a try!

Comment: @lericr...thanks for the suggestion. I tried to use 999X999 with the table but was unable to iterate down....yes ive solved it the slow way using the following 3 steps: mydata = Table[a*b, {a, 100, 999}, {b, 100, 999}] Then mydata2 = Select[Flatten[mydata], PalindromeQ] Lastly TakeLargest[mydata2, 1]

Comment: Could have used Max (instead of TakeLargest), just fyi :)

Comment: To shortcircuit the iteration when you find the first palindrome, you could use the While loop. Or you could use Do and Break. You can even do it with Table, but you'd probably have to use Throw. These are less in the "spirit" of functional programming, and kind of lead you away from idiomatic Mathematica code, but if you're working through EulerProject challenges, you'll eventually need to optimize your code in "ugly" ways.

Comment: This actually makes me a bit worried about you using EulerProject to learn Mathematica. There are probably better resources for learning the language. Some of those EulerProject problems might be frustrating to solve with Mathematica if you're not already familiar with all the "tricks" in the language.

Comment: @lericr please suggest another way to learn mathematica ! I also enjoy number theory stuffs so thats what initially led me to project euler.

Comment: @SmallFry You might be interested in this recent discussion and the suggestions in there: [What is a good book to learn mathematics with Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/273126/27951).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all those who helped make this answer possible. As someone has commented, this may be the long way home but hey,we got home :-)

```
mydata = Table[a*b, {a, 100, 999}, {b, 100, 999}]
mydata2 = Select[Flatten[mydata], PalindromeQ]
TakeLargest[mydata2, 1]
```

Im just learning my way through Mathematica so this helps a ton, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

You should store the minimum amount of information necessary. Further, you need only look at the cases for `b >= a`

```
{#[[1]], #[[2]], Times @@ #} &[
 SortBy[
   Flatten[
    Table[
     If[PalindromeQ[a*b], {a, b}, Nothing],
     {a, 100, 999}, {b, a, 999}],
    1],
   Times @@ # &][[-1]]]

(* {913, 993, 906609} *)
```

**EDIT:** If you also require the factors to be palindromes,

```
{#[[1]], #[[2]], Times @@ #} &[
 SortBy[
   Flatten[
    Table[
     If[And @@ (PalindromeQ /@ {a, b, a*b}), {a, b}, Nothing],
     {a, 100, 999}, {b, a, 999}],
    1],
   Times @@ # &][[-1]]]

(* {777, 858, 666666} *)
```

Comment: I think this answer was a bit too complex for a beginner like me to understand but thanks for contributing! the answer i came up with is below. It took some getting to and it may not be instantaneous but damnit I got the answer so now i can eat. I wasnt going to eat until I came up with an answer i could understand.

Answer (score 1):

If one wants to avoid using `PalindromeQ`:

```
all = DeleteDuplicates@
   Flatten[Table[IntegerDigits[i j], {i, 100, 999}, {j, 100, 999}], 1];

palindromes = Select[all, # == Reverse[#] &];

FromDigits@First@MaximalBy[palindromes, FromDigits]

(* 906 609 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Do[
  If[PalindromeQ[i*j], Print[{i, j, i*j}]; Break[]],
  {i, 999, 100, -1},
  {j, 999, i, -1}
]
```